# How to customize the ordering of enums?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am displaying my enums on the UI side with radio buttons.

How can I customize the ordering of the list of enums?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum user_status [:abc, :def:, :wer, :were]
```

on the UI:

```
<% User.user_statuses.each do |k,v| %>
  <%= radio_button :user_status, k %> <%= k >%
<% end %>
```

Note: The order I want is not alphabetic but a custom order.

Comment: [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) before `each ` ?

Comment: @blankman Why not keep sorted enum in the model itself?

Answer (score 4):

The order in which you define the enum **is** the order for your iterator. Ruby preserves order even for hashes (since [Ruby 1.9](https://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/), [ActiveSupport::OrderedHash](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash.html) was dropped because of this)

So

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum user_status: { offline: 0, unknown: 2, online: 1}
end

User.user_statuses.map {|s,i|s}
=> ["offline", "unknown", "online"]
```

This depicts the typical case, where you add a new status `unknown` that should not appear at the end.

If you used an array, transform it to a hash using the previous order as the numbers. **Do not** just change the order, since the enums will be badly interpreted (ActiveRecord stores the indexes, not the strings in the db, so they will be misinterpreted).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sort_by block and just manually configure. A custom sort order is a custom sort order. Even if there is simple underlying logic you'd need a case statement. Manually sorting in a block would be cleaner if you have a fixed set of data.